# Create a captive portal for android hotspot

Tags: android, hotspot, captiveportal

I would like to know if there is a way to create a captive portal to an android hotspot. More precisely, I turn on my hotspot and when a client connect to it, it is redirected to a web login page.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is an EAP (Extensible Authentication Protocol) network which requires an authentication server to do. Android phones are only capable of acting as a hotspot with open or WPA/WPA2 Personal security with an SSID and a password (unless open).